# PECL PCSC install on PHP 7.4

Tags: php, c, pecl, pcsc

I am using PHP code that relies on the package:
https://pecl.php.net/package/pcsc

Finally I need to update from PHP 5 to PHP 7 (late enough). The REMI repo for CentOS unfortunately does not support PCSC for PHP7 anymore so I tried to install it manually by using the command:

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/pcsc-0.3.1
```

But I get a bunch of errors (see below). Is there a way to solve this? Is there an alternative to access smart cards in PHP (did not find any)?

Errors:

> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:92:35: error: unknown type name
> 'zend_rsrc_list_entry'  static void
> php_pcsc_ctx_res_dtor(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC) {
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:113:36: error: unknown type name
> 'zend_rsrc_list_entry'  static void
> php_pcsc_conn_res_dtor(zend_rsrc_list_entry *rsrc TSRMLS_DC) {
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zm_startup_pcsc':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:272:53: error: 'php_pcsc_ctx_res_dtor' undeclared
> (first use in this function)
> le_pcsc_ctx_res=zend_register_list_destructors_ex(php_pcsc_ctx_res_dtor, NULL, PHP_PCSC_CTX_RES_NAME,module_number);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:272:53: note: each undeclared identifier is
> reported only once for each function it appears in
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:273:54: error: 'php_pcsc_conn_res_dtor'
> undeclared (first use in this function)
> le_pcsc_conn_res=zend_register_list_destructors_ex(php_pcsc_conn_res_dtor,
> NULL, PHP_PCSC_CONN_RES_NAME,module_number);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_is_valid_context':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:521:31: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDCONTEXT'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(context,SCARDCONTEXT,&ctx_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CTX_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_ctx_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_release_context':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:543:31: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDCONTEXT'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(context,SCARDCONTEXT,&ctx_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CTX_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_ctx_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_list_readers':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:564:31: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDCONTEXT'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(context,SCARDCONTEXT,&ctx_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CTX_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_ctx_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:580:5: error: too many arguments to function
> 'add_next_index_string'
> add_next_index_string(return_value, ptrReader, TRUE);
>
> In file included from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:37:0,
> from /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:23: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:432:14: note: declared here  ZEND_API
> int add_next_index_string(zval *arg, const char *str);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_connect':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:609:31: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDCONTEXT'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(context,SCARDCONTEXT,&ctx_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CTX_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_ctx_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_disconnect':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:634:29: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDHANDLE'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(hCard,SCARDHANDLE,&conn_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CONN_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_conn_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_transmit':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:665:29: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDHANDLE'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(hCard,SCARDHANDLE,&conn_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CONN_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_conn_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:708:58: error: macro "RETVAL_STRING" passed 2
> arguments, but takes just 1
> RETVAL_STRING(e_bytes_to_hex(recvBuffer, recvLen), TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:708:3: error: 'RETVAL_STRING' undeclared (first
> use in this function)    RETVAL_STRING(e_bytes_to_hex(recvBuffer,
> recvLen), TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_status':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:731:29: error: expected expression before
> 'SCARDHANDLE'
> ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE(hCard,SCARDHANDLE,&conn_res,-1,PHP_PCSC_CONN_RES_NAME,le_pcsc_conn_res);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:763:85: error: macro "add_assoc_string" passed 4
> arguments, but takes just 3
> add_assoc_string(return_value, "PROTOCOL", "RAW", TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:763:31: error: 'add_assoc_string' undeclared
> (first use in this function)
> add_assoc_string(return_value, "PROTOCOL", "RAW", TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:766:85: error: macro "add_assoc_string" passed 4
> arguments, but takes just 3
> add_assoc_string(return_value, "PROTOCOL", "T=0", TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:769:85: error: macro "add_assoc_string" passed 4
> arguments, but takes just 3
> add_assoc_string(return_value, "PROTOCOL", "T=1", TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:777:58: error: macro "add_assoc_string" passed 4
> arguments, but takes just 3
> add_assoc_string(return_value, "ATR", atrString, TRUE);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c: In function 'zif_scard_errstr':
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:799:53: error: macro "RETURN_STRING" passed 2
> arguments, but takes just 1
> RETURN_STRING(php_pcsc_error_to_string(in_errno),1);
>
> /var/tmp/pcsc/pcsc.c:799:3: error: 'RETURN_STRING' undeclared (first
> use in this function)
> RETURN_STRING(php_pcsc_error_to_string(in_errno),1);
>
> make: *** [pcsc.lo] Fehler 1 ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: Just ask the author to port the code to a newer PHP version (version 8 is current, btw). Or, if you take up that task yourself, extract a [mcve]. Concerning smart card libraries, that kind of question is explicitly labelled off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the developer of this extension and it is up to date since some weeks.

Just install it using the following command:

```
pecl install pcsc-beta
```

You can also get the code from https://github.com/pcsc-for-php/pcsc and compile yourself. You will find instructions on the GitHub page.

Comment: I know, actually there is a story around it. After Remi Collets answer I went to PECL and found that the extension was marked as deprecated / not active. I tried to update it myself but my skills weren't sufficient so I searched for help and I inspired Calvin Buckley (financially) to help update the extension. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Finally I need to update from PHP 5 to PHP 7 (late enough). The REMI repo for CentOS unfortunately does not support PCSC for PHP7 anymore so I tried to install it manually by using the command:

If the extension was compatible, it would be in the repository, as all [other extensions](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status)

So this looks as a dead project.